# python screenmanager (kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

```
`from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Login(Screen):
    def main(self):
        layout = GridLayout()
        def btn():
            sm.switch_to(Screen(name='account'))
        self.bt = Button(text='tela 1',
                         size_hint=(None,None),
                         size=(592,86),
                         pos=(50,50), on_press=btn,
                         background_color=(1,0,0,0))
        layout.add_widget(self.bt)
        return layout
    
class Account(Screen):
    def main2(self):
        lt = GridLayout()
        def btnn():
            sm.switch_to(Screen(name='login'))
        self.btt = Button(text='telaa 2',
                         size_hint=(None,None),
                         size=(592,86),
                         pos=(50, 50), on_press=btnn,
                         background_color=(1,0,0,0))
        lt.add_widget(self.btt)
        return lt

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(Account(name='account'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if _name_ == '_main_':
    TestApp().run()
```

`I started with kivy today, but as it is only a passing novel, I do not intend to learn kivy language.

All the tutorials I see on the internet about screen manager use kivy language.
How do I scroll through 2 screens using only python?
I tried to translate from kivy language to python but all I got was a black screen.

Comment: Can you provide an example of kivy code performing this ? You talked about trying to translate code, could you paste the kivy and the translated python here ?

Comment: show your code and full error message (in question, not in comment)

Comment: Kivy is a [module for python](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm#:~:text=A%20module%20allows%20you%20to,easier%20to%20understand%20and%20use.&text=Simply%2C%20a%20module%20is%20a,can%20also%20include%20runnable%20code.) So kivy is still written in Python. You should see it as an extension of the already existing python code. This extension can help you so that you don't have to write your own application/screen manager. I would recommend learning kivy, or to use some other [python GUI framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

Comment: wait one second

Comment: aaaaaaa im not getting to post the code or an image, what do i do?(sorry for the english, google translate.. you know)

Comment: @mmm you can just edit your first post. Simply add *edit:* `your code`

Comment: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

Comment: oh god im gonna jump from bridge

Comment: select code in your question and press CTRL+K and it will format code (and use colors) like in my answer

Comment: (amem), i started today with kivy so im sure that are more mistakes than successes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is minimal example which uses Python code (not kv language) to create `Screen` with `Button` which changes screen in screen manager.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

# Declare both screens

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layout = BoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.label = Label(text='Menu Screen')        
        self.layout.add_widget(self.label)

        self.button = Button(text='Go To Settings')
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button)
        
    def change_screen(self, event):
        #sm.current = 'settings'
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'up'
        self.manager.transition.duration = 3 # 3 seconds
        self.manager.current = 'settings'
        
class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.layout = FloatLayout()
        self.add_widget(self.layout)

        self.label = Label(text='Settings Screen')        
        self.layout.add_widget(self.label)

        self.button = Button(text='Go To Menu', size_hint=(.5, .10), pos=(20, 20))
        self.button.bind(on_press=self.change_screen)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.button)

    def change_screen(self, event):
        #sm.current = 'menu'
        self.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        self.manager.transition.duration = 0.5 # 0.5 second
        self.manager.current = 'menu'

# Create the screen manager

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Based on example (which uses kv language) from documentation [Screen Manager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html)

Comment: thank you!! but how do I use in this code "FloatLayout()"? thats what im using to the background, buttons, labels etc

Comment: it doesn't matter if you use it directly in `Screen` or in `FloatLayout()` which is in `Screen`- you have to only add `FloatLayout()` to `Screen` and `Button` add to `FloatLayout()`

Comment: BTW: I added `self.manager.` instead of `sm.` - so it is more universal. I also added `transition.direction` and `transition.duration` so `Screens` can move in different directions with different speed.

Comment: thank u man. last thing, what does that creepy stuff do "super().__init__(**kwargs)"? (**kwargs??)

Comment: in `def __init__(self, **kwargs)` it gets all named arguments as dictionary and in `super().__init__(**kwargs)` it puts these arguments to run original `__init__`

Comment: thanks :) BTW: I added `FloatLayout` and `BoxLayout` in code.